# Using this.$nuxt.$router.push in Nuxt 3 page url changes but new page isn't being rendered

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxt3

Using Nuxt 3 I am trying to navigate to new pager which is located in pages/my-custom-page/index.vue. After clicking the button the url chanes but page content is never being udpated. When I refresh the url It takes me to the desired page. What's the issue?

I've tried to use navigateTo, $router.go and other options but no luck.

```js
generateNewPage() {
    this.$nuxt.$router.push({
        path: '/my-custom-page',
        query: { selectedValues: this.selectedValues }
    });
},
```

For some reason im getting this error when trying to route to anywhere

```
chunk-3NMN3MUW.js?v=43929ae8:7946 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')
    at remove (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js?v=43929ae8:7946:1)
    at Object.remove (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js?v=43929ae8:6812:1)
    at unmount (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js?v=43929ae8:6488:1)
    at unmountChildren (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js?v=43929ae8:6584:1)
    at unmount (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js?v=43929ae8:6491:1)
    at unmountComponent (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js?v=43929ae8:6564:1)
    at unmount (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js?v=43929ae8:6478:1)
    at unmountChildren (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js?v=43929ae8:6584:1)
    at unmount (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js?v=43929ae8:6493:1)
    at unmountChildren (chunk-3NMN3MUW.js?v=43929ae8:6584:1)
```

EDIT: After debugging for a while the issue seems to be related to Swiper some how. I have Swiper controls in separate component. When I remove it from one of my components the routing starts to work. I haven't quite figured out how to fix it.

this is what my Swiper controls component looks like

```
<template>
    <Teleport to="#swiper-control-left">
      <button @click="swiper.slidePrev()" class="slider-control-left">
        <sliderLeft />
      </button>
    </Teleport>
    <Teleport to="#swiper-control-right">
      <button @click="swiper.slideNext()" class="slider-control-right">
        <sliderRight />
      </button>
    </Teleport>
</template>
<script>
import { useSwiper } from "swiper/vue";
import sliderLeft from "@/assets/icons/slider-left.svg";
import sliderRight from "@/assets/icons/slider-right.svg";

export default {
  components: {
    sliderLeft,
    sliderRight,
  },
  setup() {
    const swiper = useSwiper();

    return {
      swiper,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: do you have a transition or a watcher ?

Comment: Not in this component no but I am using some transitions on the same page.

Comment: can you try removing the transition from the page and see if that fixes it ? there is an open issue on github related to this https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13309

Comment: Removed every transition from my project but no luck. Thanks for the suggestion! I'll keep looking into this bug.

Comment: Same thing happens with NuxtLink